# EPPlus: "Column out of range" error with LoadFromCollection

Tags: epplus

I am getting a "Column out of range" error with LoadFromCollection   - code follows. Insert into the SampleApp that comes with EPPlus to replicate.

Did I do something screwy or is it a bug? Or a config setting that I haven't set?

```
public class tst
    {
        public string Name;
        [Description("Created Time")]
        public DateTime Created_time;
    }


     var pck = new ExcelPackage();

            var kpcollection = new List<tst>();
            for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                kpcollection.Add(new tst
                {
                    Name = "line" + i.ToString(),
                    Created_time = DateTime.Now
                });
            }

            var wsenum = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("KPTest");
            //Load the collection starting from cell A1...
            wsenum.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(kpcollection, true, TableStyles.Medium9);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in EPPlus library and it [has been reported on September 25, 2017](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/8).

Comment: This bug is only when using List<dynamic>.  The issue of the OP would be resolved with Harish's answer.  EPPlus works on properties with an accessible setter.

Answer (score 3):

Add Properties  like `{ get; set;}` for each variable, because the way epplus works is on properties of class.

For example, instead of using:

```
class student
{
    int num;
   string name;
}
```

use this:

```
class student
{
     int num { get; set; }
     string name { get; set; }
}
```